# using Linq to find all indexes of a matrix satisfying a certain condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this 2 dimensional boolean matrix `A`

```
public bool[10][10] A;
```

Is there a Linq that does what the method below does? (returning all indexes `i` so that for a given `n`, `A[i][n]` is true)

```
public List<int> getIndex (int n)
{
   List<int> resp = new List<int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       if (A[i][n])
       {
          resp.Add(i);
       }
   return resp;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, A.Length).Where(x => A[x][n]).ToList();
```

should do. Otherwise you can make the whole thing lazy by returning an `IEnumerable<int>`

```
public IEnumerable<int> getIndex (int n)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, A.Length).Where(x => A[x][n]);
}
```

Comment: Or even `Enumerable.Range(0, A.Length)...`

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<int> getIndex (int n)
{
    return A.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }) 
            .Where(x => x.x[n])
            .Select(x => x.i)
            .ToList();
}
```

Should do what you want.